# How to detect clicks (touch) on specific parts of 3d model?

Tags: android, 3d

I need to load a 3d model to my app (is not a game, not that it makes any difference) and detect when the user touches specific parts of this model, to take different actions.

How can I do this? Is it possible?

Comment: Could you provide more info about these actions? Is this a true 3D app that would allow the model to rotate freely, and that would allow the user to navigate through 3D space? If so, then you could consider using OpenGL ES for Android. OpenGL is one of the frameworks that makes interactive 3D possible. Once you have OpenGL or some other 3D framework installed, you would convert the 2D touch point to a ray cast into 3D space, then check for intersections. Check https://android-arsenal.com/tag/2 for a framework that does most of the work for you. OpenGL can be a bit rough to learn.

Comment: I need a single activity that loads a 3D model (currently loading an OBJ file), allows the user to rotate this model around its axis (centered on screen). This model has been splitted into several objects in the Blender file before exporting to OBJ, then I'd need to detect the interaction on any of these splitted objects (dor, window, side mirrors, etc). I'm currently using Rajawali, but it is not a requirement.

Comment: I'll post an answer below just to have more space, but feel free to ask more questions in the comments. I won't have time to dig into Rajawali, but I can describe in general terms how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Rajawali, but GitHub describes it as an OpenGL ES framework. As you described it in the comment above, you'll need to consider two basic user actions, and one action I'll add as helpful:

1. Swipe across the screen in some direction: change in X, change in Y.
2. Touch at some (x,y) point on screen with the car in some orientation.
3. (Optional) Zoom in/out to make it easier for a user to select small features such as side mirrors.

Depending on what OpenGL ES details Rajawali exposes, you'll need to do one or both of the following:

- Learn about the four matrices that determine how a 3D scene is rendered on a 2D screen.
- Find the Rajawali functions with names such as "lookAt" or "setViewpoint," and learn how to pass screen gesture info to these functions.

You can read about the four OpenGL matrices at length elsewhere. Even if Rajawali simplifies the coding a bit you should learn a bit about those matrices. Although your first inclination is to change the "model" matrix that affects the object's position and orientation, it's more likely that you'll be manipulating the "view" matrix that determines the point and direction in space from which the user sees the car. That is, the car will actually remain centered at (0,0,0), and the user's swipes, touches, and pinches will change the viewpoint.

Constraining movements so that the vehicle is always centered is nice both because your code can be a little simpler, and also because the user can't "lose" the car by sliding the viewpoint too far to one side.

The simplest change of viewpoint is a zoom, which in most iterations means simply changing the Z translation of the viewpoint matrix. Rajawali may make this simpler by providing zoomIn() and zoomOut() functions. Otherwise you'll need to do this:

1. In the callback or "event handler" provided by Rajawali/Android for a pinch, get the pinch-in or pinch-out value.
2. Call the Rajawali zoomIn() or zoomOut() function, if it exists. You will likely need to scale the value so that the amount of pinch matches expectations for zooming in and out of a car model.
3. Alternately, set the Z translation component of the view matrix.

Converting an (x,y) 2D screen touch point to a ray cast into 3D space can be tricky if Rajawali doesn't provide an appropriate function called something like "screenToWorld" that accepts a point in 2D screen space and a 3D point or 3D ray in world space. Spend time googling for "ray casting" for Rajawali. Here's a brief overview of what the code will need to do:

1. Convert a 2D touch point into a 3D ray pointed into the screen.
2. Check for the intersection(s) of the 3D ray and various subobjects.
3. (Optional) Change the color or otherwise highlight the selected object.

OpenGL does not provide a ray casting function, and I don't recommend implementing it on your own unless you have no choice. Various frameworks that wrap around or supplement OpenGL may provide this function. OpenGL coders will fault me for this description, but from memory here's how to convert a 2D touchpoint into a 3D ray pointing into the screen:

1. Get the (x,y) 2D screen touch point from a "touch" or "click" callback or event handler in Rajawali or Android.
2. Convert the 2D touch point to a 3D point. If I remember, this means setting Z to some value such as -1, 0, or 1. This is the base point of the ray.
3. Define a second 3D point with a different Z value. This is a far point of the ray.
4. Use the screen, projection, and view matrices to transform the 3D points into "world" space.
5. Given the 3D world coordinates for your base point and far point, use ray-object intersection to determine what object is intersected.

Again, Rajawali may provide some function that determines which object(s) are intersected by the ray. If multiple objects are returned, then pick the closest object. Since your vehicle is already subdivided into multiple subobjects this shouldn't be too hard. Implementing pinch-to-zoom can make it easier for a user to select a small object.

Swiping is analogous to a mouse move for OpenGL, and many starter projects for OpenGL describe how to convert a mouse move to a rotation. Assuming for the moment that the model rotates only about the vertical axis from the ground through the roof, then you simply need to change left/right swipes to positive/negative rotations about what in OpenGL is typically the Y-axis.

1. From Android/Rajawali, handle the "swipe" event handler or callback. This is analogous to a "mouseMove" function.
2. Translate the left/right swipe into a negative/positive value.
3. Call the rotateAboutY() function, if available, OR apply a rotation to the viewpoint matrix (which I won't describe here).

Given all that, I would suggest the following approach:

1. See if Rajawali provides convenience functions to convert screen coordinates to a world ray, to convert a screen swipe to a rotation, and to test a ray intersection with a series of objects.
2. Even if Rajawali provides these functions, read a little bit about the low-level OpenGL ES underneath, and the four matrices: screen, perspective, viewpoint, and model.
3. If Rajawali doesn't provide the convenience functions, look for a framework that does OR see if some other library that works with Rajawali can provide these convenience functions.
4. If you can't change frameworks or find a framework that hides the messy details, plan to spend a week or more studying OpenGL closely. You probably don't need to know about shaders, textures, etc., but you will need to understand the OpenGL 3D space, the four matrices, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation.

Comment: You're certainly welcome. I hope your project goes well.